# Magnitude ambiguity of a signal with a frequency equal to system pole in unit-less plot and Bode plot

Tags: control-system, bode-plot

Suppose we have a first order system (H(s)=1/(s+p)) having a pole at s=-p. Now, to this system we are passing a sinusoidal signal having a frequency same as the frequency of the pole. Since H(s)= 1/0= \$\infty\$ but in the Bode plot it shows it has a finite gain, in fact it is -3dB \$=(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}) \$ if the dc gain is 0 dB. I may be mixing real and imaginary part and I understand that we take only the imaginary part for frequency response, but what is the significance of real part then? It seems that imaginary part gets real and real part getting imaginary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I may be mixing real and imaginary part*

Yes you are.

> *I understand that we take only the imaginary part for frequency
> response*

Yes, the bode plot x-axis is \$j\omega\$.

> *what is the significance of real part*

These pictures [from my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/) may help. They're for a 2nd order low pass filter that has a small peak in the frequency response. However, the axes and concepts are still the same for a 1st order transfer function. First is the amplitude part of the bode plot: -

[image]

And, if we could look in 3 dimensions we would see this equivalent: -

[image]

For your first order system, the pole would sit on the α axis at -p.

> *It seems that imaginary part gets real and real part getting
> imaginary.*

Just blame the math guys.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to understand the concept of "complex frequencies" s=sigma+jwt.

You are asking for the behaviour of the 1-st-order system when "*we are passing a sinusoidal signal having a frequency same as the frequency of the pole*". However, such a frequency (just the real part of s) does not exist in reality !

In general: In reality, it is not possible to excite a system with a signal having a complex frequency s. The concept of complex frequencies was introduced for theoretical analyses only.

On the other hand, the Bode plot shows the magnitude and phase response (measured or simulated) of a system for real sinusoidal signals only. For veryfing the observed -3dB point you must use the complex s-plane.

Answer (score 0):

One definition of a pole is that it is the value of s which makes the transfer function go to infinity.

In your simple first order transfer function the value of s which makes the transfer function go to infinity is -2. Therefore we can plot that single pole on the real axis of the s-plane at a position of -2.

However if we want to plot a Bode plot of the transfer function we must put the transfer function in the form k/(Ts+1) in order to isolate (find) the value of k which is the DC gain and then we must find the magnitude and phase of the transfer function.

Our new form of the transfer function (if we divide throughout by 2) becomes 0.5/(0.5s+1) and we see that the DC gain has a value of 0.5.

There is a pole on the Bode plot at 1/T = 2 rad/s and if we substitute s=jw and w=2 into either form of the the transfer function and then calculate the magnitude and phase using the standard formula we have-

magnitude at 2 rad/s = 1/(sqrt(2^2+2^2) = 0.3535

phase = 0 degrees - arctan(2/2) = -45 degrees.

We can see that the gain is 0.707 (-3 dB) of the DC gain at the pole frequency (0.3535/0.5 = 0.707)

So, the point is that the value of the transfer function goes to infinity at the pole but the magnitude of the transfer function is -3 dB down at the pole frequency.